# What's the direct way to open the screen @ Control panel >> System

Tags: windows, control-panel

I was wondering what's the direct way to go straight to the screen at `Control Panel >> System`:

[image]

For example, to go straight to `Advanced System Settings`, I could simply open `C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is a keyboard shortcut that should be direct enough.

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>/<kbd>Break</kbd>

Or you could go to the context menu of (right-click) 'Computer' and click 'Properties'.

Comment: To be frank, this is not what I'm looking for. I'm not looking for a **shortcut**, but the *direct way* to do it. **The lowest layer** I mean. Stuff like Windows + Pause/Break is just not going to work across all versions of Windows.

Comment: For example, go `System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` is an instruction that will work across all windows. Regardless of what display settings the user has.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `control` utility with the appropriate cpl.

```
control sysdm.cpl
```

[Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149648?wa=wsignin1.0) is a list of the control panel applications with their corresponding cpl file.
And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is documentation on how to show a particular tab after opening the window.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding it, `control sysdm.cpl` doesn't open the window as shown in the question. It opens the window that i'm citing as an example.. Btw I was trying to find the file path for control panel but couldn't do so.. do you know what's the file path for control panel?

Comment: For the control panel just run control without any arguments. Otherwise sorry for the wrong cpl file, I'm on Windows XP right now so I can't test. But as soon as I get on my Windows 7 pc I'll try and tell you.

Comment: No you are right `control` is working but I wanted it to point to `control >> System and Maintenance >> System`

Comment: I'm sorry I still couldn't try on Win 7 yet. Try `control sysdm.cpl,,3` and try with different numbers at the end, it should be one of them.

Comment: They aren't working I've tried `sysdm.cpl,,0` to `sysdm.cpl,,6`. Btw I'm vista

Comment: First link is broken. Please check/edit the answer.

Comment: @Leonel Fixed :)